# Why does this Xaml Path crash silverlight?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

Quick easy points for anyone who knows the answer:

The following Xaml path works fine in WPF but crashes in Silverlight. I can verify this behaviour in Kaxaml.

The path code is

```
<Path Fill="#FFEDEDED" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#FFA3A3A3" Opacity="0.7" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry Figures="m 1 2 l 4.0525 5.2361 l 4.0527 -5.2361 z "/>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

The exception is a script error

> Unhandled error in Silverlight Application. Failed to create a
>   System.Windows.Media.PathFigureCollection from the text 'm 1 2 l
>   4.0525 5.2361 l 4.0527 -5.2361 z'

Its supposed to draw a triangle like so:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unlike WPF Silverlight does not support converting a string to Figures.

---

I got the following underline/hover error message in Expression Blend:

[image]

---

The equivalent triangle, authored via Blend, for Silverlight is:

```
<Path Fill="#FFEDEDED" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#FFA3A3A3" Opacity="0.7" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Data="m 1 2 l 4.0525 5.2361 l 4.0527 -5.2361 z" />
```

Comment: @GoneCoding What if there is FillRule present in the PathGeometry? Something like 
`<PathGeometry Figures="M234.7 811l27 -27.2L288.9 811l-27.2 27.4L234.7 811Z" FillRule="NonZero"/>`