# XamlParseException occurred: Failed to create a 'System.Windows.Media.Geometry' from the text

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I am Still learner and facing some issue in my application.

I have String of Geometry and i want to display it on silver light application.
I am using following code to display it , Where "GeoObject" is string which is markup of geometry.
Geometry is very big and with more point in it.
Something this code work fine and something it doesn't work and gives me error"Failed to create a 'System.Windows.Media.Geometry' from the text ".
I am trying to find out problem but yet couldn't find it.

Is here anyone who has faced such problem ? if yes then have you find solution?

```
string nsPath ="<Path xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\" Data=\"";
var section = (System.Windows.Shapes.Path)XamlReader.Load(nsPath + GeoObject + "\" " + "</Path>");
```

My Geometry string is too big so i can not post it here .....
when i put that string in static path object in design window of Silver-light application ,geometry is shown perfectly but when i run it it shows me same error.

when i put that string in static path object in design window of WPF application ,geometry is shown perfectly and also runs perfectly.

Help me Please..........

Comment: Just improved some formatting. Your sample ends with "/Path>", that should be "</Path>". Is this a typo in your question or also in your code?

Comment: Please check it out now.

Comment: I'm not familiar with xaml that well, but does this post help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331549/why-does-this-xaml-path-crash-silverlight

Comment: Maybe it's just too big. Is there any InnerException in the XamlParseException?

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues, the first maybe formatting. In the debugger verify your path is what you think it is. Since we can't know how GeoObject ToStrings as (what it returns upon the call to the overload ToString) we on StackOverflow can't diagnose.

Also I believe that the sample is wrong and that the generated path object is failing with a wrong node ending. Use this node ending fix and **check each line** in the debugger to make sure you are getting the path you want and the cast you want

```
string nsPath ="<Path xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\" Data=\"";

var path = string.Format("{0}{1}\"/>", nsPath, GeoObject);
var xmlResult = XamlReader.Load(path);
var section = (System.Windows.Shapes.Path) xmlResult;
```

If that is working, verify what the path points to is actual data...maybe there is a permission problem or the code is not reading the data where you think it is...