# display xaml image in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a problem getting vector image to display on a page

This should work, shouldn't it?

```
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="./Assets/vectorImage.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

I'm afraid that the problem is in xaml image file which was created from bitmap with Inkscape. vectorImage.xaml is quite large (136KB) so i won't copy the whole file, but it starts like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Viewbox xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Stretch="Uniform">
<Canvas Name="svg2985" Width="126" Height="198">
    <Canvas.Resources/>
    ...
```

EDIT:

`<ResourceDictionary Source="./Assets/vectorImage.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>` has red underline and hint : Inheritor of the ResourceDictionary is expected.

When i run the application i get following excetion

```
An exception of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in app.exe but was not handled in user code

WinRT information: Failed to assign to property 'Windows.UI.Xaml.ResourceDictionary.Source'. [Line: 134 Position: 68]
```

EDIT:

One thing i forgot to mention is that project is windows store app

Comment: But what is the problem? It does not compile? It compiles but displays nothing? It throws exception?

Comment: oh.. sorry.. i edited post.

Comment: You're setting the `Resources` property of the `ContentControl` which, in itself, does nothing.  You need to set the `Content` property for anything to be displayed, but offhand I'm not sure how to get your file to display as the content.

Answer (score 3):

1) assign `x:Key` to your `ViewBox`, which is most likely causing your error

```
<ViewBox x:Key="MySvgImage" ....>
```

2) move resource at least 1 level above `ContentControl`, for example to `Window` resources like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary Source="./Assets/vectorImage.xaml"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

3) change `ContentControl` like this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{StaticResource MySvgImage}"/>
```

4) if this is really the beginning of your `vectorImage.xaml` `ResourceDictionary` then it should start and end like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   <Viewbox x:Key="MySvgImage">
      <Canvas Width="126" Height="198">
         ...
      </Canvas>
   </Viewbox>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: almost.. now im getting exception: WinRT information: Failed to create a 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageSource' from the text 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAH4AAADGCAYAAAAUujSQAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAIABJREFU....

Comment: Can you find `data:image/png;base64` in your `XAML` and tell me how it is used? Don't need whole value, only how it is used.

Comment: <Image xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="image2993" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Source="data:image/png;base64,..." Width="126" Height="198"/>

Comment: I also tried to remove it, but then i got: WinRT information: Failed to create a 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.PathFigureCollection' from the text 'm 22.895833 195.89583...

Comment: last error was related to post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331549/why-does-this-xaml-path-crash-silverlight. new exception is: WinRT information: Failed to assign to property 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContentControl.Content' because the type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.ResourceDictionary' cannot be assigned to the type 'Object'

Comment: it looks like, for whatever reason it's trying to assign `ResourceDictionary` to `Content`. Do you know which control causes the problem? Is it that `ContentControl`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30987/discussion-between-maxlego-and-dkozl)