# How to convert SVG file to XAML in windows 8 / WinRT

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, svg, windows-8, windows-runtime

How i can convert SVG file to XAML in windows 8 / WinRT. I am new to this XAML / SVG environment. So anyone please help me to implement the same in windows 8. I need to parse this svg file and need to display the content in the page through code.

Comment: While similar in nature, SVG and XAML aren't the same ... I'm not sure what you're trying to do? Do you just need to do a one-time "parse" for development purposes? For that there were Xaml exporters for Adobe Illustrator, and Microsoft Expression Design 4 is now free ... it might do it.

Comment: No i need to parse that svg file through code, this is for plotting maps. I will get the map boundaries in the form of SVG file and i need to parse this and plot it in a canvas during run time

Comment: Use WinJs instead of Xaml or host a browser. Both can natively show SVG content.

Answer (score 56):

For me the simplest way to do it is the following:

1. Open your **.svg** file in free vector drawing tool [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/)
2. Save as "Microsoft XAML (*.**xaml**)"

Also you may need to update the result output file a bit after conversion, since not all XAML processing engines support converting a string to Figures (as described in the accepted answer to [Why does this Xaml Path crash silverlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331549/why-does-this-xaml-path-crash-silverlight)). So, for example, if you have this:

```
<Path Fill="#FFEDEDED" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#FFA3A3A3" Opacity="0.7" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry Figures="m 1 2 l 4.0525 5.2361 l 4.0527 -5.2361 z "/>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

then you will need to change it to this:

```
<Path Fill="#FFEDEDED" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#FFA3A3A3" Opacity="0.7" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Data="m 1 2 l 4.0525 5.2361 l 4.0527 -5.2361 z" />
```

**- OR -**

You could use a bit different way to export the **xaml** from [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/), described by *Tim Heuer* in accepted answer to the question [Convert SVG to XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624070/convert-svg-to-xaml/18624512), because both ways produce different xaml output:

> Method (yes, superhack):
>
> - Use Inkscape to save as PDF
> - Rename the Filename extension from PDF to AI
> - Use Expression Design to open AI document
> - Export to Silverlight Canvas

**UPDATE (2015-08-25)**

I've found my self using the second ("hack") way more and more often rather then first (more straightforward) one, because it creates more "expectable" XAML as I would call it.

Comment: +1 even though this still _feels_ like a hack.  One would think that by now the tools would give you a way to save it like you wanted to save it.

Comment: @JesseChisholm it indeed feels like a hack to me too! Yet it still works even for Windows 10 development today :)

Comment: Note, Inkspace has a "Silverlight Compatible" option when you save as xaml. Can you check if that fixes your issue? I don't use silverlight

Comment: If I try the `Expression Design` method I get *Cannot assign text value 'F1 M 0,0L 46.5193,0L 46.5193,46.5193L 0,46.5193L 0,0' into property 'Clip' of type 'RectangleGeometry'*. Which export option do you use? `XAML Silverlight 3 Canvas` or `XAML Silverlight 4 / WPF Canvas`. What are your other settings (Text, Live effects, ...)? Does the svg/pdf/ai need a certain size? Which one? What name do you use, when you want to embed the xaml? `vectorgraphic.xaml`?

Comment: @testing I export as "XAML Silverlight 4 / WPF Canvas" with all effects rasterized: http://i.imgur.com/YX33cAD.png. Also the export file name is totally up to you (just add .xaml extension to it)

Comment: Incscape hasn't the Method to Save a File as Microsoft XAML (*.xaml)

Answer (score 4):

I cheated and converted my SVG to a font. First, I created the SVG, then using IcoMoon created the font. https://icomoon.io/app/#/select.

I downloaded the font's ttf into my assets folder with content.

[image]

Next I add the code. Notice the font filename, then #, then the name of the font. The text should be

```
    <TextBlock Text="&#xe901;" FontFamily="/Assets/icomoon.ttf#icomoon" FontSize="45"</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at this article:
[Transforming SVG graphics to XAML Metro Icons](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2012/07/26/Transforming-SVG-graphics-to-XAML-Metro-Icons.aspx)
You can find here a way to convert via transforming to XPS.

You can use also an [Svg2Xaml](http://svg2xaml.codeplex.com/) converter.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free converter available in the Microsoft Store (as standalone Windows application). It is called [SVG to UWP XAML Converter](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/svg-to-uwp-xaml-converter/9P5RQ15T5CWJ).

It worked without any problems converting my multi-color SVGs correctly as batch to XAML, which I added to Visual Studio within a WPF User Control (for a preview you need to select the SVG file manually)